# MFRC522 - Impedance control with External Antenna

Tags: pcb, antenna, rfid, impedance-matching, mfrc522

I am a newbie into the world of RFID. For one of my upcoming designs, I am using the chip MFRC522 and an external antenna. The antenna is W7001. 
As you can see in the datasheet,

[image]

It is mentioned that the impedance is 50/80. ***Could you please tell me what this means ?***

Further, I have done my calculations for finding requisite passives values for EMC filter, matching circuit and antenna. 
In these calculations, I have chosen R match to be 50 Ohms. ***Can you please confirm if this is correct for the antenna chosen?***

The schematic as of now looks something like this.
[image]

So, my next question is depending on Rmatch, how will trace widths and trace impedances of TX1 and Tx2 change ? i.e. Lets assume Rmatch is 50 Ohms. Does it mean that single endedly both lines ( Tx1 which runs upto L1 , Tx2 which runs upto L2 ) have to  be 50 Ohms impedance matched in the PCB ?

Hope I have clarified myself. It would be really great if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not need to be impedance matched, the frequency of the RFID signals for the MFRC522 is 13.52MHz. Transmission line effects don't start for most applications until roughly 50MHz. You may also want to look [at this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=199983.0;attach=178517) if you haven't.